# In the provided question of AM-GM inequality in the description, I'm not able to figure out which manipulation was used here, in the solution?

Tags: inequality

> Let $x, y, z \in \Bbb R_{> 0}$ such that $xyz=1$. Prove that $$\frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)} + \frac{y^3}{(1+x)(1+z)} + \frac{z^3}{(1+x)(1+y)} \ge \frac{3}{4}$$

---

Now, in the first step they suggested that we can use AM-GM in the following form

$$\frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)} + \frac{(1+y)}{8} + \frac{(1+z)}{8} \ge \frac{3x}{4}$$

I am wondering what manipulation they did in the first step to write the following expression as stated above? A little help is appreciated.

Comment: I understood the question but while going through the solution,I couldn't figure out how did they manipulate the original expression into the expression into the expression I mentioned next in my question

Comment: @Dr.Mathva ,  I've now made necessary edits. A little help,will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  What is the context?

Comment: This is a problem from IMO's shortlisted problems 1998.

Comment: The question is about the application of AM GM inequality theorem.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ,you may view this picture for a reference. It is an image attachment of the question with a solution.  https://ibb.co/89y1BBt

Comment: Maybe, I'm not able to get my point across,this picture may help.

Comment: Please include such information in the question itself.

Comment: They used AM-GM for three terms, i.e.: $$\frac{\frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)} + \frac{(1+y)}{8} + \frac{(1+z)}{8}}3 \geqslant \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)} \frac{(1+y)}{8} \frac{(1+z)}{8}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3}{64}}=\frac{x}4$$ Multiply both sides $\cdot 3$ to obtain the desired expression. They then add cyclically, i.e. they consider the same inequality but with $(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,z,x)\mapsto (z,x,y)$ and add everything up.

Comment: Does the question mention AM-GM?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ,The question,itself doesn't mention it but it was under the topic of application of AM GM inequality.

Comment: Again, please include such information in the question itself.  Comments are ephemeral. If a moderator having a bad day deletes these comments, such information is lost.

Answer (score 2):

The expression wasn't rewritten, those other two terms were more or less poofed into existence. Implicitly we're saying

$$\frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)} + \frac{y^3}{(1+x)(1+z)} + \frac{z^3}{(1+x)(1+y)}$$ $$ = \frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)} + \frac{y^3}{(1+x)(1+z)} + \frac{z^3}{(1+x)(1+y)} + \frac{(1+y)}{8} + \frac{(1+z)}{8} - \frac{(1+y)}{8} - \frac{(1+z)}{8}$$

Why does that help? Because cyclicly adding and subtracting those two terms and then applying AM-GM on all three resulting expressions gives

$$\frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)} + \frac{y^3}{(1+x)(1+z)} + \frac{z^3}{(1+x)(1+y)} \geq \frac{3(x+y+z)}{4} - \frac{(3+x+y+z)}{4}$$

$$ = \frac{x+y+z}{2}-\frac{3}{4}$$

Can you finish the last step?